# How do I not show a Visual Studio designer for an inherited DataTable

Tags: .net, visual-studio, inheritance, ado.net, datatable

My business objects inherit from `System.Data.DataTable`. When I double-click on one of these classes from the Solution Explorer, it opens in design mode and says "To add components to your class, drag them...". I want it to open like any other class and to show the code. By decompiling the DataTable class using Reflector, I see that it uses the Editor attribute. I tried adding this to my class with an empty constructor, but the behavior didn't change. I also tried changing the DesignTimeVisible attribute. Here are the attributes for a DataTable:

```
[Serializable, 
XmlSchemaProvider("GetDataTableSchema"), 
Editor("Microsoft.VSDesigner.Data.Design.DataTableEditor, Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"), DefaultEvent("RowChanging"), 
DesignTimeVisible(false), 
DefaultProperty("TableName"), 
ToolboxItem(false)]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the file and Select "Open With..." Select CSharp Editor (or whatever) And the select "Set As Default"

Then hit OK. From then on double click will open in whatever you selected as default for that class.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anyone knows how to mark a class as not having a designer.

Comment: You can also use this to avoid showing the designer for a UserControl or other custom control.

Comment: The Set as Default applies to *ALL* files, not just the offending one that has it confused.